# Splitting string separated with comma with Regex instead of String.split

Tags: java, regex

Is there any way I can split this string using the Pattern and Matcher classes in Java using regex instead of using `String.split()`?

```
o_9,o_8,x_7,o_6,o_5
```

I have tried doing it with `"\\w"` but it just returned one group in `m.group()` which is `o`. It should have matched everything except the commas. Could someone help me with this string split?

Comment: What is wrong with using `String.split` ?  Regex isn't good at dealing with patterns of arbitrary length.  Would you always have 5 CSV separated items, or could the number of items be variable?

Comment: the appropriate regex would be `/[^\,]+/` I believe. But will prefer a String.split approach as mentioned by @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: But [`String.split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) takes a *regular expression*.

Comment: Well, I am using string.split in my code. I have to do improvements in running time and I just found out that string operations take a lot of time. I have achieved a 3 min difference in running time if I use regex in my code which usually takes 4 min without it. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, it does. But, here I am talking about Java's regex package.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `"\\w+"` instead of just `"\\w"`.  If that doesn't help, we'll need a more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: @AlanMoore I want to get all the comma separated values of a string whose size could vary. For example, if the string is o_9,o_8,x_7,o_6,o_5,x_4,x_3,x_1, I want to get a list of all the comma separated values here. And "\\w+" worked but only gave the first value as an output, o_9 from the string mentioned.

Comment: @AlanMoore "\\w+" does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you've gone wrong, but in your reply to AlanMoore's helpful suggestion you said you could only match the first word. The code below shows that it matches all the words:

```
    String s = "o_9,o_8,x_7,o_6,o_5";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        String matchedWord = m.group();
        System.out.println("Matched \"" + matchedWord + "\".");
    }
```

Output:

```
Matched "o_9".
Matched "o_8".
Matched "x_7".
Matched "o_6".
Matched "o_5".
```

For performance, the Pattern should be compiled once - preferably as a `private static final` near the top of your class. Avoid creating an array of strings (as `String.split()` does) unless you really need to.

Comment: I see what I did wrong now. I was trying to print out all the values from the matcher by printing m.group(0), m.group(1) instead of using a while loop on m.find(). Rookie mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
String str = "o_9,o_8,x_7,o_6,o_5";
String[] getstr = str.split(',');
String str1 = getstr[0];
String str2 = getstr[1];
String str3 = getstr[2];
String str4 = getstr[3];
String str5 = getstr[4];
```